# Selenium & Beautiful Soup Returning Different len() Values on Same Website Scrape (amazon)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In the code example below, I get different results for the `print(len(block1))` item at the end of the code.  I cannot seem to figure out what is causing this:

- my code,
- page loading with Selenium,
- some sort of anti-scrape method that Amazon uses, or
- a silly thing I am missing.

My ten most recent results were

```
LOG: 3/14/2020 - 2:30pm EDT 
Length Results for 10 separate runs:
0 / 20 / 55 / 25 / 57 / 55 / 6 / 59 / 54 / 39
```

```
# python version: 3.8.1
#Import necessary modules
from selenium import webdriver # version 3.141.0
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # version 4.8.2

#set computer path and object to chrome browser
chrome_path = r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

# search Amazon for "bar+soap"
# use 'get' for URL request and set object to variable "source"
browser.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=soap+bar&ref=nb_sb_noss_2")
source = browser.page_source

#use Beautiful Soup to parse html
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

#set a variable "block1" to find all "a" tags that fit criteria
block1 = page_soup.findAll("a", {"class":"a-size-base"})

#print the number of tags pulled
print(len(block1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I am new to all this, this format is more clear and concise.  Learning the ropes over here in Virginia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct. I modified it a little to make sure everything is fine, so I collected tags with both Selenium and Beautiful Soup and counted, they always match.

I was getting very different results at first, so I added 7 sec wait after page load. This made things more stable, so it is possible that some of the elements just take longer to load and when you count are not on the page.

This didn't fully solve the issue. I am still getting different results, for 10 runs, I got 64(2), 65(6), 67(2).
My recommendation for you would be to:

1. try adding and increasing `sleep` and see how it behaves;
2. try actually printing out the results and see what is the difference between runs;
3. potentially, just use the result that you get most often because a lot of websites run product [A/B tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) and there can be multiple UI/content variants for the same page or different components of the same page (this is very likely our case). So every time we run the script, we get into a certain A/B variant or probably a combination of variants, which leads to these results.

Just in case, my code:

```
#Import necessary modules
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

#set computer path and object to chrome browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# use 'get' for URL request and set object to variable "source"
browser.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=soap+bar&ref=nb_sb_noss_2")
sleep(7)
source = browser.page_source

#use Beautiful Soup to parse html
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

#set a variable "block1" to find all "a" tags that fit criteria
block1 = page_soup.findAll("a", {"class":"a-size-base"})
#print the number of tags pulled
print('BS', len(block1))

# To be save, let's also count with pure Selenium:
e = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.a-size-base')
print('SEL', len(e))
```

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Wow thanks!  I am going run the code with your modifications and try some more troubleshooting. Thank you so much for helping me troubleshoot this.  I will see how far I get with what you suggested.  I have learned a lot of good tricks from this, thank you!

Comment: I just ran 9 times  with a sleep(60) on a loop and got the following: 49(1), 59(1), 61(1), 62(1), 63(3), 64(2).  I had not thought about the A/B variant you mentioned.  I will consider this resolved, thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if there are other factors, like screen size or geo location that could lead to us having different results as well. I am definitely getting more 65s than any others and you don’t have it at all.